# Julia - Plotting minimum spanning tree with GraphPlots

Tags: plot, graph, julia

I'm using the package LightGraphs.jl to generate a minimum spanning tree:

```
LightGraphs.kruskal_mst(g)
```

The output is an array of edges:

```
4-element Array{SimpleWeightedEdge{Int64,Float64},1}:
Edge 6 => 9 with weight 1.0
Edge 8 => 9 with weight 1.
Edge 9 => 10 with weight 1.0
Edge 6 => 11 with weight 1.0
```

My question is then how to plot this spanning tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. The best way to do this is to create a new graph, and
then use the output from `kruskal_mst()` to populate the new graph. Here is an example:

```
g_mst = SimpleWeightedGraph(size(g)[1]) #Create a new graph
for ew in kruskal_mst(g)
   add_edge!(g_mst,ew.src,ew.dst,ew.weight)
end
gplot(g_mst)
```